# Can the Pixlr API be used to add/edit text?

Tags: image, image-processing, image-editing, image-editor

I'm developing an online tool that involves image editing. Pixlr is my first choice for use, but one thing I noticed while looking around the developer area is that there is no option to add/edit text to an image.

See examples of Pixlr API [here](http://developer.pixlr.com/). Even in the "Open Image Editor" example, which to me implies the full editor suite of tools, there is no option to drop text onto an image. Is there a way to do this? Or perhaps another online tool (or self-hosted) solution to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I clicked on your link for the API examples, clicked the last image under "Open image editor", and one of the five options at the bottom was to add text:

[image: screenshot of Pixlr interface]